# Time taken for a particle to slide down parabola

Tags: calculus, physics

Consider a particle sliding down $f(x)=x^2$ under the influence of gravity and without friction. The particle always remains on the curve - that is, it does not have any 'air-time'.

If we start the particle from position $(a, a^2), a>0$ with no initial velocity, how can we work out the time it takes to slide without friction to the origin?

I figured that I could just use its horizontal movement as means to work out total time:

Its horizontal acceleration can be worked out to be $$a_{x}=\frac{g}{2}\sin{2\theta}$$ where $\theta$ is the angle that the tangent to the curve makes with the $x$-axis at the point $(x,x^2)$.

We can simplify this to be:

$$a_{x}=g\left(\frac{2x}{1+4x^2}\right)$$

Have I done all of this right? If so, where do I go from here??

I would love any help with this.

Comment: Horizontal and vertical parts are hardly relevant. You should split $\vec g$ into the _tangential_ and _normal_ components, then throw out the latter.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Could you please elaborate on why the horizontal and vertical accelerations are not relevant in solving the question?

Comment: It was only my gut feeling which may or may not be accurate. Maybe the problem can be solved your way too. Maybe it even will turn out to be the easier way. Now, imagine a particle moving along a circle _without any gravity_; it will still have some non-zero acceleration due to curvature. Aren't you overlooking that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have that by energy conservation

$$\frac12mv^2=mgh \implies v=\sqrt{2gh}=\sqrt{2g(a^2-x^2)}$$

then

$$ds=vdt \implies dt = \frac{ds}v \implies T=\int_0^Tdt = \int_0^a \frac{\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{\sqrt{2g(a^2-x^2)}}dx$$

---

For example for $a^2= 1\,m$ and assuming $g=9.8 \,m/s^2$ we [obtain](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int%20%281%2B4x%5E2%29%5E.5%2F%282*9.8*%281%5E2-x%5E2%29%29%5E.5%20dx%20x%3D0..1)

$$T= \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{\sqrt{2\cdot9.8(1-x^2)}}dx \approx 0.60\, s$$

---

As suggested in the comments by [Travis Willse](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/155629/travis-willse), we can express the result in a more elegant way by $\xi =\frac x a$

$$T =\frac1{\sqrt{2g}} \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1+4a^2\xi^2}}{\sqrt{1-\xi^2}}d\xi=\frac{E(-4a^2)}{\sqrt{2g}}$$

where E is the [complete elliptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind) integral of the second kind.

---

Here is a graph to compare the time taken to fall down from a given height $h$ along the parabola and directly in a vertical path $(T_0=\sqrt{2h/g})$

[image]

Comment: It's perhaps not worth a separate answer, but an exact expression for $T$ is $\sqrt{\frac{4 a^2 + 1}{2 g}} E\left(\frac{2a}{\sqrt{4a^2 + 1}}\right)$, where $E$ is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind.

Comment: @TravisWillse Thanks for the comment, I also noticed a typo meanwhile. Yes it can be a nice way to express the result, tha way I've given the result is not the best indeed! But I hope it works fine.

Comment: @TravisWillse I try to express it in a better way.

Comment: I did not mean to suggest my expression was better; I meant only to point out that the definite integral can be expressed nicely in terms of an already-defined function.

Comment: @TravisWillse With "better" I mean in a nicer way. Thanks for the suggestion, I add something on that.

Comment: The graph suggests that $T$ has a nonzero limit as $a \to 0$, and it turns out to be $\frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2 g}}$.

Comment: @TravisWillse Indeed I was thinking about that, it is a little counter-intuitive at first. I think it depends on the fact that slope becomes very small at the origin. So it takes some times to the particle to start moving and reach the origin.

Comment: @user Thankyou very much for this answer! How difficult would it be to find an $n$ such that the time taken for the particle to slide down $x^n$ from $a=1$ to the origin is minimized?

Comment: @cherrytree That would be a good question to post separately.

Comment: @cherrytree Using the same idea we can ideally solve for “any” path. Let try for example for the simpler $y=x$ or $y=kx$.

Comment: @user I was actually curious in that regard and decided to do so. Using your method, I found the time taken for any function $f(x)$ from the point $x=a$ to $x=b$ (if it is possible) to be: $T=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2g}}\int_{b}^{a}\sqrt{\frac{1+f'\left(x\right)^{2}}{f\left(a\right)-f\left(x\right)}}dx$

Comment: @cherrytree Yes with the condition that $v> 0$ which is included in $f(a)-f(x)>0$.

Comment: @user I also assume that $f(x)$ has to be concave up between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: It is not necessary it is convex, we only need that $v>0$.

Comment: @user As per my question stating that the particle has 'no air time', then it is not necessary, but if we want to model a more realistic scenario, having it convex will ensure that it remains on f(x).

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Take focal length as  $ f= \frac14 ~\text{in} ~y(x)= x^2/(4f)  \tag 1 $ to tally dimension

Slope $ y'(x)= \dfrac{x}{2f}=\tan \phi \tag 2 $

$$ dt=\frac {ds}{v}=\frac {dx \sec \phi }{v} \tag 3 $$

Velocity is decided by y coordinate of fall from rest

$$ \frac12 m v^2= mgh,~ v=\sqrt{2 g y} \tag 4 $$

Plug in from 1) , 2) ,4) into 3) and integrate.

Verify if possible that it takes more time than the cycloid under same circumstances.. Brachistochrone.